# IndexedDB Reference Error: db is not defined

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, firefox-os

I'm trying to create an application for Firefox OS which basically needs to store some data using IndexedDB.

The store() function is called when the user clicks on a submit button which results in the creation of the name and description variables an user submitted form.

However, I keep getting a Reference Error saying my db object is not defined. Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's my current code:-

```
function store () {
    // create the transaction with 1st parameter is the list of stores and the second specifies
    // a flag for the readwrite option
    var transaction = db.transaction([ 'Apps' ], 'readwrite');

    //Create the Object to be saved i.e. our App details
    var value = {};
    value.name = name;
    value.desc = description;

    // add the details to the store
    var store = transaction.objectStore('Apps');
    var request = store.add(value);
    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        alert("Your App data has been saved");
    };
    request.onerror = function (e) {
        alert("Error in saving the App data. Reason : " + e.value);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
// variable which will hold the database connection
var db;

    if (window.indexedDB) {
        console.log("IndexedDB is supported");
    }
    else {
        alert("Indexed DB is not supported!");
    }

    // open the database
    // 1st parameter : Database name. We are using the name 'Appsdb'
    // 2nd parameter is the version of the database.
    var request = indexedDB.open('Appsdb', 1);

    request.onsuccess = function (e) {
        // e.target.result has the connection to the database
        db = e.target.result;

        console.log(db);
        console.log("DB Opened!");
    }

    request.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };

    // this will fire when the version of the database changes
    // We can only create Object stores in a versionchange transaction.
    request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
        // e.target.result holds the connection to database
        db = e.target.result;

        if (db.objectStoreNames.contains("Apps")) {
            db.deleteObjectStore("Apps");
        }

        // create a store named 'Apps'
        // 1st parameter is the store name
        // 2nd parameter is the key field that we can specify here. Here we have opted for autoIncrement but it could be your
        // own provided value also.
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore('Apps', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });

        console.log("Object Store has been created");
    };

});
```

Comment: r u geeting IndexedDB is supported in log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the scope of the `db` variable. Currently you have the following line `var db;` declared inside of the `$(document).ready` function. Move its declaration to a more global scope i.e. outside of this function and the variable will be visible in the `store()` function too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This worked! I was experimenting with the example from your blog and mixed up the variable scope. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var value = {};
value.name = name;
value.desc = description;
```

assign value to the name and description.
name=formname.name.value
description=formname.description.value

Comment: This was what I had earlier done, however, the problem lied in the scope of the db variable.